# Value is not getting parsed in my markdown previewer

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My previewer worked OK until I add the function to the rendered section and everything just disappeared I tried to sort out that what was the problem. The problem either lies some where in here:

```
getRawMarkup(){
    return {__html: marked(this.state.value, {sanitize: true}) };
}
```

Or here:

```
<div>
    <div class="title-input">VIEWER</div>
    <div>
        <div class="content" id="preview" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getRawMarkup()} />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [link](https://codepen.io/ridabatool/pen/oNdMgmo?editors=0010) to my project.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use it this way

```
  getRawMarkup(){
    marked.setOptions({
      sanitize: true,
    })
    return { __html: marked.parse(this.state.value) };
  }
```

But according to documentation please remember this

> If true, sanitize the HTML passed into
> markdownString with the sanitizer function. Warning: This feature is
> deprecated and it should NOT be used as it cannot be considered
> secure. Instead use a sanitize library, like DOMPurify (recommended),
> sanitize-html or insane on the output HTML!